# Laravel Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando con laravel 6.6, he creado un modelo llamado salidas todo funciona bien hasta que mando a llamar los datos de la tabla me muestra el error Base table or view not found: 1146 Table tengo agregado en los modelos todas las tablas correspondientes

controlador salida utilize un foreach para mandar llamar datos de otra tabla, los cuales son los que deseo que muestre la vista:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $salida = new Salida;
    $salida->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $salida->vehiculo_id = $request->vehiculo_id;
    $salida->fecha_salida = Carbon::now();
    $salida->save();

    foreach ($request->herramientas as $herramienta){
        $salida_detalle = new SalidaDetalle;
        $salida_detalle->salida_id = $salida->id;
        $salida_detalle->herramienta_id = $herramienta;
        $salida_detalle->save();
    }
```

tabla salidas:

```
 Schema::create('salidas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('vehiculo_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('vehiculo_id')->references('id')->on('herramientas')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('gaveta1');
        $table->string('gaveta2');
        $table->string('gaveta3');
        $table->dateTime('fecha_salida');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

tabla Salidas_detalle:

```
 Schema::create('salidas_detalle', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('salida_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('salida_id')->references('id')->on('salidas')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('herramienta_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('herramienta_id')->references('id')->on('herramientas')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

vista:

```
@foreach ($salidas as $salida)
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ $salida->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $salida->user->rpe }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $salida->vehiculo->numero_economico }}</td>
                    <td><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/{{ $salida->gaveta1 }}" alt=""></td>
                    <td><img class="card-img-top" src="images/{{ $salida->gaveta2 }}" alt=""></td>
                    <td><img class="card-img-top" src="images/{{ $salida->gaveta3 }}" alt=""></td>
                    <td>{{ $salida->detalle}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $salida->fecha_salida }}</td>


                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Tanto el modelo Salida como el modelo SalidaDetalle tiene el atributo `pretected $table` ?

Comment: no, solo el modelo SalidaDetalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent esta tratando de ubicar una tabla en tu base de datos cuyo nombre sea similar al de la clase asignada al modelo (*esto siguiendo las convenciones de nombres*)

Ejemplo:

- Si el modelo es **`Usuaria`** entonces la tabla debería ser **`usuarias`**, para evitar tener que hacer configuraciones extra
- En cambio si el modelo es **`Usuaria`** pero la tabla se llama `integrantes` entonces deberás definir la propiedad `$table` y asignarle como valor el nombre de la tabla de tu bd, así:

  ```
  protected $table 'integrantes';
  ```

Entonces como te encuentras en el segundo caso, debes hacer lo siguiente en el modelo `Salida`

```
protected $table = "nombreTabla";
```

Aunque claramente para el problema expuesto no infiere, considero que las tablas pivote no tendrían por que tener un modelo que las represente, en cambio para eso pudiéramos auxiliarnos de las relaciones de Eloquent,

Por otro lado si ya lo tienes creado dicho modelo, considera que la regla del nombre de la tabla igual puede influir y deberás por cada modelo que no cumpla la convención entonces declarar la propiedad ya antes expuesta.

Además de lo anterior, revisa el último enlace que indica que reglas se deben seguir para modelos de tablas intermedias.

- [Aquí puedes leer mas de las convenciones de nombres](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)
- [Trabajando con relaciones Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- [Definir modelos para tablas intermedias](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)

Comment: Sugieres que no tome en cuenta el modelo SalidasDetalle?

Comment: si gracias por tu respuesta, soy nueva en este mundo de la programación

Answer (score 0):

No te imaginas la ayuda que me han dado, WOW, he pasado horas tratando de resolver por que el Seeder no me funcionaba.... Habia olvidad ese detalla de la convención de nombres de laravel...

Mil gracias

Comment: Hola Franc, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos,  .

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.